# More visible legend entries for only filled pgfplots bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, legend

How can I get more visible legend images next to the textual legend entries `A, B, C`? The default for only filled bar charts seems to consist only of a hair thin vertical line, which makes it quite difficult to discern multiple colors:

[image: pgfplots bar chart with narrow legend entry images]

I assume that my answer is closely related to changing the legend image code as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224677/30821), but I could not get the (renamed `ybar` to `xbar`) `/pgfplots/xbar legend/.style` segment to influence my output.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  xbar stacked,
  legend pos=south east,
  y post scale=.5]

\addplot[fill,blue!50] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
\addplot[fill,red!50] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
\addplot[fill,brown!50] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1) (2,2) (3,3)};

\legend{A,B,C} % why so narrow, my dear legend images?
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Two updates**

1. Adding `xbar legend=fill` to the `axis` options fills the legend images.
2. Almost there: `legend image post style={yscale=2,yshift=-.75ex}` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272986/30821) make the filled area almost square and I can adjust the vertical position properly.

What's missing: How can I get rid of the vertical line?

Comment: `xbar legend` as option for the `axis` environment?

Comment: @esdd: Thanks, `xbar legend=fill` already is half-way how I'd want it. I struggle with the right syntax to get a plain, filled square as the legend entry.

Comment: The `xbar legend` contained a defect. I have fixed that such that your MWE will compile correctly with the next stable version of pgfplots (will be 1.13).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the legend images should be square your own legend style could be

```
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/my xbar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
      \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=.5em]
      plot coordinates { (\pgfplotbarwidth,0.1em)};}
}}
```

and use `my xbar legend` as `axis` option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  /pgfplots/my xbar legend/.style={
    /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
      \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=.5em]
      plot coordinates { (\pgfplotbarwidth,0.1em)};}
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xbar stacked,
  legend pos=south east,
  y post scale=.5,
  my xbar legend
  ]
\addplot[fill,blue!50] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
\addplot[fill,red!50] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
\addplot[fill,brown!50] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
\legend{A,B,C}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: D'oh... even after almost 2 years of TikZ, I had missed that the `.../.style` definition simply would allow me to introduce a new custom name. I thought the `\pgfplotsset` invocation would somehow modify default values.